# Extract values from xml document by xidel using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, xidel

Trying to extract 'text and value' pairs from all lines of DNS XML output using Xidel/Xpath but have no luck with such expression:

```
xidel -e "/status/section[*]//item[*]@value/@text"
```

In fact, I am not able to extraxt any single pair nor single value :-/ Anybody know Xpath better?

BTW: Stackoverflow entering box says there are mostly code and ask me for more details, but I have no idea what kind of details could be added....

Source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<status>
  <section id="general" text="General Status">
    <item id="state" text="Current state" value="1" valueText="Running" />
    <item id="uptime" text="Server uptime" value="573262" valueText="6 days, 15 hours, 14 minutes, 22 seconds" />
    <item id="zones" text="DNS zones" value="13" />
    <item id="cached" text="DNS records cached" value="88756" />
  </section>
  <section id="InReq" text="DNS Requests Received">
    <item id="total" text="Total" value="20810744" />
    <item id="udp" text="UDP" value="20810402" />
    <item id="tcp" text="TCP" value="342" />
    <item id="rd" text="Recursive (RD)" value="20599874" />
    <item id="OpCode0" text="OpCode 0 - Request" value="20810732" />
    <item id="OpCode5" text="OpCode 5 - Update Request" value="1" />
    <item id="OpCode10" text="OpCode 10 - unknown" value="11" />
    <item id="QType1" text="Query record type A" value="16596407" />
    <item id="QType2" text="Query record type NS" value="4425" />
    <item id="QType5" text="Query record type CNAME" value="439" />
    <item id="QType6" text="Query record type SOA" value="13101" />
    <item id="QType12" text="Query record type PTR" value="1849989" />
    <item id="QType15" text="Query record type MX" value="8529" />
    <item id="QType16" text="Query record type TXT" value="41016" />
    <item id="QType28" text="Query record type AAAA" value="2084624" />
    <item id="QType29" text="Query record type LOC" value="2" />
    <item id="QType33" text="Query record type SRV" value="104612" />
    <item id="QType35" text="Query record type NAPTR" value="90" />
    <item id="QType38" text="Query record type A6" value="49" />
    <item id="QType43" text="Query record type DS" value="654" />
    <item id="QType48" text="Query record type DNSKEY" value="14" />
    <item id="QType51" text="Query record type NSEC3PARAM" value="1" />
    <item id="QType60" text="Query record type TYPE60" value="35" />
    <item id="QType99" text="Query record type SPF" value="16" />
    <item id="QType252" text="Query record type AXFR" value="6" />
    <item id="QType255" text="Query record type *" value="106719" />
    <item id="typeOther256" text="Other query types" value="4" />
    <item id="classIN" text="Query class IN" value="20810649" />
    <item id="classCH" text="Query class CH" value="80" />
    <item id="classOther256" text="Other query classes" value="3" />
  </section>
  <section id="DropReq" text="Dropped/Ignored DNS Requests">
    <item id="total" text="Total" value="510261" />
    <item id="repeat" text="Repeat requests" value="510261" />
    <item id="ipblock" text="IP Blocking" value="0" />
    <item id="stealth" text="Lame request Stealth option" value="0" />
    <item id="notify" text="Notify request not matched" value="0" />
    <item id="maxrecur" text="Exceeded max. parallel recursive" value="0" />
    <item id="ignoreroot" text="Ignored UDP request for &lt;root&gt;" value="0" />
    <item id="ignoreudpany" text="Ignored UDP 'ANY' request" value="0" />
    <item id="ignoreplugin" text="Ignore DNS request plug-in" value="0" />
  </section>
  <section id="OutResp" text="DNS Responses Sent">
    <item id="total" text="Total" value="20300475" />
    <item id="aa" text="Authoritative (AA)" value="176020" />
    <item id="tc" text="Truncated (TC)" value="1430" />
    <item id="ra" text="Recursion Available (RA)" value="20032753" />
    <item id="rcode0" text="RCODE 0 - No Error" value="16196886" />
    <item id="rcode1" text="RCODE 1 - Format Error" value="262" />
    <item id="rcode2" text="RCODE 2 - Server Failure" value="35985" />
    <item id="rcode3" text="RCODE 3 - Non-Existent Domain" value="3943192" />
    <item id="rcode4" text="RCODE 4 - Not implemented" value="80" />
    <item id="rcode5" text="RCODE 5 - Query Refused" value="124070" />
  </section>
  <section id="OutReq" text="DNS Requests Sent">
    <item id="total" text="Total" value="5220257" />
    <item id="notify" text="Notify" value="6" />
    <item id="zt" text="Zone transfer" value="7" />
    <item id="ixfr" text="Incremental zone transfer (IXFR)" value="53" />
    <item id="soarefresh" text="Zone SOA refresh" value="0" />
  </section>
  <section id="InResp" text="DNS Responses Received">
    <item id="total" text="Total" value="5152878" />
  </section>
  <ReqPerSec>39,42,48,40,38,36,40,41,26,31,35,18,26,31,19,32,19,32,35,45,22,24,33,18,32,35,17,34,46,37,29,25,46,55,22,36,35,36,40,34,44,34,40,36,21,17,20,36,17,33,31,26,23,27,40,51
,31,40,25,42</ReqPerSec>
</status>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-e "//item/concat(@text,' - ',@value)"
```

Would return:

```
Current state - 1
Server uptime - 573262
DNS zones - 13
```

etc.

```
-e "//section/(let $a:=@id return item/concat('[',$a,'] ',@text,' - ',@value))"
```

Would add the section id in front of each line:

```
[general] Current state - 1
[general] Server uptime - 573262
[general] DNS zones - 13
```

etc.

**[edit]**
Although the use of a variable works just fine, it's not really necessary, because the `id` attribute of the `<section>` element node, a level higher, can be accessed by prepending `../`:

```
-e "//item/concat('[',../@id,'] ',@text,' - ',@value)"
```

Or with `xidel`'s extended string syntax:

```
-e "//item/x'[{../@id}] {@text} - {@value}'"
```

**[/edit]**

Comment: Just discovered that there are multiple sections with same "text" content like "total". Is it posiible to distinc in what section it resize, e.g. print ID of Section with each line? This will be best for consequent parsing...

Comment: Thanks, this is EXACTLY what I need, and it give me hint how to handle variables in Xpath ;-)